# working with decimals in java, converting large numbers into smaller ones with a decimal point

Tags: java, android, decimal

unfortunately I was never good with math but I would like to know how would I take a number like 5800 and turn it into 5.8, or a number like 43400 and turn it into 43.4 in java?

Comment: From right to left, Count the number of zeros and shift the dot one step to the left aftwards?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn it into"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what is the general format of the input ? and what is your expected format output ? XX.X or X.XX ?

Comment: That explains his question mark.

Comment: Argh, can't count to three. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use float or double.

```
float decF = (float)5800/1000;
//or
double decD = (double)43400/1000
```

Comment: And this produces 5.0 and 43.0 because you are doing integer division.

Comment: Oh my bad, forgot to cast. Why 100? Surely 5800/1000 = 5.8 as the question says?

Comment: No, you were right, I can't count to three. 1000 is right. 8-(

Answer (score 2):

Heres a way:
Double d = 5800;
Double c;
c = d/1000;
Doubles do hold decimals. Look here for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html.

Comment: Doubles hold double-precision floating point values. They only become decimals when you print them out as such...

Answer (score 1):

See this

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/102.html